# Does OR evaluate the entire condition if the first portion matches?

Tags: python

In python, if I have the following code:

```
a = True
b = True

if (a == True) or (b == True):
    // Do stuff
```

My question is, in that if statement, does it check to see if `b` is `True` after it's already seen that `a` is `True`?  Or does it execute the code in the if statement as soon as it sees that `a` is `True`

Comment: See the linked question's answers. No, the `b == True` part is not evaluated if `a == True` is true. (This is true of most, but not all, programming languages in terms of their *logical* "and" and "or" operators.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware that it was called short-circuiting.  Thank you very much for the responses.

Comment: :-) Yeah, I saw the question and (not being a Python guy) was able to find the answer because I happened to know what it's called. Happy coding!